# Setting the java path to a latest version in linux permenently

Tags: java, linux

i have compiled some java files in windows which contains java 1.6.x, moved the compiled java files to linux and tried to run them. But i got version mismatch error as the path in linux is pointing to java 1.4.2 version.

There is java 1.6 is also installed in the linux machine.

How can we set the java path to java 1.6.x permanently, i.e when we set the path using export command the path will be lost when we restart the session. I would like to set this path permanently as we set this in windows environment variables dialog box.

Can anyone please help me on how to set the java path permanently and removing the old path in linux?

Comment: Most modern linux support alternative installations of things like java. I think this question is better suited for Superuser or even Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: This question could be aimed specifically at configuring the Java JDK, i.e. Java Development Kit, a tool used for programming.  Slightly unfair "closed" motion here, imho.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choices :

- Define an environment variable in /etc/environment. You declare in this file your JAVA_HOME and give it the path to your JDK. I don't know if this file exists on every distribution but on Debian based distros (Ubuntu, Mint ...) it exists. The pros is that the variable is available for all the programs you launched.
- Or you define the variable in your $HOME/.bash_rc. This variable will be available in all the terminal you opened. The problem with this method is that the variable will be available only for commands launched from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup configuration in `/etc/profile` . Add your `JAVA_HOME`  and `PATH` variable.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.x/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.x
```

Reference :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

**EDIT**

run 
`source /etc/profile` 
after saving the changes above in `/etc/profile`

Comment: Make sure you run  "source /etc/profile" after saving the changes above in /etc/profile, to make them take effect immediately.

Comment: thank you @fuzzyanalysis edited

Answer (score 0):

As you said `export`, considering that your shell is `bash`.
Under the user's home directory, you have `.bashrc` file. Just add your java path to `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variable as below in `.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME="<your java home>"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME is currently pointing to java 1.4.2 so your compiled code uses this version to run although java 1.6 is installed. Update your JAVA_HOME environment variable as follows,

```
export JAVA_HOME="<your java 1.6 home>"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH"
```

old path is removed and this path will always be used.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux javas are installed in **/usr/lib/jvm/**.
There might be directories jdk-1.6.0 and jdk-1.6.1. And a symlink jdk-1.6 pointing to the latest 1.6.1 (or so).

You may ask which java is on the path with:

```
which java
```

You might use the linux `update-alternatives` to handle such things.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "java" /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6/bin/java
```

(Or `--set`.) Do a bit of an internet search as my recollection is a bit rusty.